# How to display or hide the div through binding

Tags: knockout.js

For Eg:

In viewModel,

```
//Makes webApi call to get the data from some repository
function GetData() {
            var data = http.get(apiUrl)
            .success(function (result) {
                 if (result != null || result !='')
                 {
                    // success display the data
                    vm.dataDisplay;
                 }
               else {
                    vm.errorMsg('No data');

                }
            })
```

//viewModel

```
 var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            dataDisplay: ko.observableArray(),
            errorMsg:ko.observable(''),
           };
        vm.activate();
        return vm;
```

//view.
Expected.

```
If( errorMsg == 'No Data')
{
// show errordata div and hides displayData div
<div class="errorData" data-bind="text:errorMsg"/>
}
else
{
// Show displayData div and hide errorData div
<div class="displayData" data-bind="text:dataDisplay" />
}
```

How to implement this through binding??

I can use ko attr or visible.
But my requirement is to hide/show through binding only.
Please suggest me how to do this?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right, you just need to use the [`visible`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding, which would only show the HTML element if the value of the observable is NOT a null, undefined, or empty string. This should work:

```
<div class="errorData" data-bind="visible: errorMsg, text:errorMsg"/>

<div class="displayData" data-bind="visible: dataDisplay, text:dataDisplay" />
```

Also, if "dataDisplay" is indeed an array, you have to use:

```
<div class="displayData" data-bind="visible: dataDisplay().length, text:dataDisplay" />
```

Comment: You should not have to add the `()` - if you do that, you're binding the literal value, and not the observable itself

Comment: @JosephGabriel you're right, it's only necessary for the array visibility. Ah, well... it's the end of the day soon. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: <div class="errorData" data-bind="visible: errorMsg, text:errorMsg"/>. In visible: errorMsg, the errorMsg will be true/false, then only we can display the text:errorMsg.So i have modified like below: <div data-bind:"visible:displayError, text:errorMsg />.Here displayError is boolean observable(true/false).if its true the errorMsg will display otherwise it will be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method as it will help you solved what you are trying to implement

```
self.ClickLoad=ko.observable(false);
self.Enable=ko.observable();
Enable=function(){
    self.ClickLoad=ko.observable(true);
    console.log(self.ClickLoad);
}

<div data-bind="visible: Enable()">
    <p>sjknscjksnajcn</p>
</div>
```